# Combining RoleNeed's with Flask Principal

Tags: python, permissions, flask, acl, flask-principal

I'm trying to create a permission that requires that the user has role A or role B.

According to [Python Flask Principal](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/) documentation, the following line creates a permission that requires the user has roleA AND roleB.

```
combined_permission = Permission(RoleNeed('roleA'), RoleNeed('roleB'))
```

Do you know how to create a permission relying on a OR instead of a AND ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it currently stands, needs of a combined permission are checked with an `OR`. Quoting from [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/#flask_principal.Permission):

> *class* flask_principal.**Permission**(**needs*)
>   Represents needs, any of which must be present to access a resource

If you want an `AND` instead, simply sub-class the `Permission` class and override [the `allows` method](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-principal/blob/81ee6b7d658e7cd3200c0efc5bbb706215526082/flask_principal.py#L328-L339) to check that intersection of the sets is the same as the needs of the permission in the first place:

```
class RequiresAll(Permission):
    def allows(self, identity):
        if not has_all(self.needs, identity.provides):
            return False

        if self.excludes and self.excludes.intersection(identity.provides):
            return False

        return True

def has_all(needed=None, provided=None):
    if needed is None:
        return True

    if provided is None:
        provided = set()

    shared = needed.intersection(provided)
    return shared == needed
```